# Extracting values from Strings with seemingly no uniform delimiters

Tags: python, string

I have a log file with lines of **strings** similar to this

```
Aug 25 06:45:55 #TS=1598337955#SP=domain.org/shibboleth#IDP=domain.org/idp/shibboleth#USERID=john#DEPT=staff
```

These lines of strings consist of values; Date, TS, SP, IDP, USERID and DEPT whereas...

```
Date = Aug 25 06:45:55
TS = 1598337955
SP = domain.org/shibboleth
IDP = domain.org/idp/shibboleth
USERID = john
DEPT = staff
```

Can someone please suggest me a way to extract these values e.g. TS and USERID from these strings? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. In your sample you don't have `#UID=`, you do have `#USERID=`. Is that a mistake? If so, please [edit] your question. I also recommend taking the [tour], to familiarize yourself with the way things work around here. For example you need to show your own efforts.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and I greatly apologise for not realising the mistake, it was indeed USERID. I'm a beginner with Python and I had scoured thru for a solution to this but all of my findings couldn't be replicated for my use case because they either have a uniform trend of delimiters that could be split and extracted through a list or they have strings with fixed index (always starts at 10th char and ends at 15th for example). I'm now testing the solutions from answers to see if they work and update accordingly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex (works):

```py
import re

for line in reader:
    linex = str(line)
    ts_value = re.findall('#TS=(.+?)#', linex)
    uid_value = re.findall('#USERID=(.+?)#', linex)
```

Appending the results into lists will have the output:

```
[['1598337955']]
[['john']]
```

If you don’t want to use any external library than use this (does not work):

```py
for string in strings:
    for element in string.split('#'):
        if 'TS' in element:
            ts_value = element
        if 'USERID' in element:
            uid_value = element
```

Comment: I might be wrong myself actually. I didn't know you could chain quantifiers like `.+?` but matching `TS=\d+` might be more reliable.

Comment: @Kraay89 you are right for TS but i don’t know if TS is only numeric it could be alpha numeric but what i know here is value of TS lies between # and starts with #TS,

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've found that the regex solution works with a little bit of tweaking by parsing the lines into strings first. this gives the output: ```['TS=1598337955']``` and ```['USERID=john']```
may I ask if you know how that code can be tweaked further to give me only their values and not include their 'keys' e.g. ```1598337955``` instead of ```TS=1598337955```

Comment: yes use re.findall('#TS=(.+?)#', linex) or re.findall('#TS = (.+?)#', linex) anything inside brackets is included in result

Comment: This works perfectly! May I edit the answer accordingly and accept your solution as best answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
def extract_from_log(log_line, label):
  if label[-1] != '=':
    label += '='
  start = log_line.index(label)
  end = log_line.index('#', start + len(label))
  return log_line[start + len(label): end]

print(extract_from_log(log_line, 'TS'))
print(extract_from_log(log_line, 'USERID'))
```